# Rails: Registration form accessible via different route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration

I have a function that redirects to a countdown while our system is offline, however I'd still like registration to be available from the countdown page (as opposed to the registration page).

Can I change the current registrations view (if so, how?) to still use the registrations_controller, or will I have to add redundant code to my application_controller to make this work?

I'm a rails newbie, so speak slowly, please. :)

*In summation,* I have a working system, but don't know how to make the registration form work from outside it's current location. (Because I followed tutorials)...

Using devise and an alternate registrations_controller: 
`Controller:`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :get_teams
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => resource.inactive_message.to_s if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
...

private
  def get_teams
    @teams = Team.all.map{ |p| [p.team_name, p.id]}
  end
end
```

`registrations.html.erb:`

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you redirect to the countdown with a before filter... something like:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :redirect_to_countdown_if_offline

  def redirect_to_countdown_if_offline
    #do check & redirect
  end
end
```

if so, you just need to put a skip_filter on the registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_filter :redirect_to_countdown_if_offline
  ...
end
```

Comment: Looks good--the error I'm currently encountering is this: 'undefined local variable or method `resource`' for...this is because my view is trying to reference `resource` in the `application_controller`, but that in the `registrations_controller`...How do I make this reference properly?  I'm removing the filter/redirect right now so I can make sure registration works outside of the default route...

Comment: different issue... to access resource, it needs to be a class level variable.  Make it `@resource` everywhere you reference it in both the view and controller, then you should be good to go.